# What does a solution like r5 or c15415 mean when i use solve() from SageMath (Python)?

Tags: python, sage

i implemented a system of complex valued functions and i solved it with sagemath's "solve" method.

In my solutions array i find entries like:

x1 == r5 or for different cases x1 == c15403. (and so on with diffent numbers)

Does the r5 stand for an arbitary rational number and c15403 for arbitary complex number?

Maybe someone can give me a hint where to find such stuff in the documentation.

Ty and have nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 'c' stands for complex. I think that 'r' stands for real, 'z' stands for integer. I don't know if there is a symbol for rationals. I don't know where it's documented, but I believe this comes from Maxima, which Sage uses as a solver. See the documentation for `new_variable` at https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_346.html#Functions-and-Variables-for-to_005fpoly_005fsolve, and in particular look at the first code example.

The Sage reference manual mentions the `r` and `z` prefixes in [the documentation of the `solve` method of symbolic relations](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/relation.html#sage.symbolic.relation.solve). Slightly amended excerpt:

> If there is a parameter in the answer, that will show up
> as a new variable. In the following example, `r1` is an
> arbitrary real (hence the `r`).
>
> ```py
> sage: forget()
> sage: x, y = var('x, y')
> sage: solve([x + y == 3, 2*x + 2*y == 6], x, y)
> [[x == -r1 + 3, y == r1]]
> sage: b, c = var('b, c')
> sage: solve((b - 1)*(c - 1), [b, c])
> [[b == 1, c == r...], [b == r..., c == 1]]
> ```
>
> Especially with trigonometric functions, the dummy variable
> may be implicitly an integer (hence the `z`).
>
> ```py
> sage: solve(sin(x) == cos(x), x, to_poly_solve=True)
> [x == 1/4*pi + pi*z...]
> sage: solve([cos(x)*sin(x) == 1/2, x + y == 0], x, y)
> [[x == 1/4*pi + pi*z..., y == -1/4*pi - pi*z...]]
> ```